# How does the adjoint linearly map between elements of tangent spaces of two different points on the manifold?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose we have a Lie Group $G$. Then we know that at the identity $\mathcal{E}$, we can create a tangent space that is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{m}$. Through a mapping (using the "vee" and "hat" operators to map between skew-symmetric matrices and their vector representations), we can effectively treat the Lie algebra as a vector space rather than a matrix space. Suppose we have some element $\tau\in\mathfrak{m}$ that is in "vector form".

Suppose we also have another point $\mathcal{X}\in G$. Then we can also define a tangent space at that point on the Lie group manifold as well. My background in physics says that we can't directly compare the $\tau$ in the tangent space at $\mathcal{E}$ to some other $\tau'$ in the tangent space at $\mathcal{X}$ because we'd be comparing vectors that live in different tangent spaces. To do this, we'd have to transport $\tau'$ from the tangent space at $\mathcal{X}$ to the tangent space at $\mathcal{E}$.

The adjoint is apparently a way of doing this: $\text{Ad}_\mathcal{X} : \mathfrak{m}\to\mathfrak{m}; \exp(\tau) \mapsto \mathcal{X}\exp(\tau)\mathcal{X}^{-1}$. Intuitively, I understand this as a linear map that sends elements in the tangent space at $\mathcal{X}$ to an element in the tangent space at $\mathcal{E}$. (Is this the correct interpretation?)

But I also know that, on a manifold, there are an infinite number of ways to get from $\mathcal{E}$ to $\mathcal{X}$ and, if we had something like a Levi-Civita connection, we could define a geodesic as an "optimal" way to get from $\mathcal{E}$ to $\mathcal{X}$. But, in the definition of the adjoint, we don't specify which path we take from one element on the manifold to the other.

How does the adjoint consistently map an element of a tangent space at some point on the manifold to the tangent space at some other point on the manifold without knowing the path between the two elements?

For context, I'm trying to reconcile what I know about Riemannian geometry (from general relativity) with the statement that "A Lie Group is also smooth manifold". If a Lie Group is a manifold, then how can we relate two tangent spaces without parallel transporting elements of those tangent spaces along some geodesic? Does the group structure or structure of the Lie algebra somehow provide that implicitly?

Comment: Lie groups are (very) special manifolds, namley there exists a multiplication morphism $m:G\times G \to G$ satisfying certain properties. Fixing $g \in G$ you have a (left) multiplication $L_g:G \to G$. Its derivative (tangent map) at the neutral element $e \in G$ is $D_e L_g : T_e G \to T_g G$ and relates two tangent spaces over different points. Since $L_{g^-1}$ is inverse to $L_g$, the differential is  an isomorphism. This can also be pressed in to the context of a metric/geodesics.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, because that differential $D_e$ mapping $T_e G$ and some $T_g G$ is an isomorphism, in the context of geodesics, there's always a unique geodesic from $T_e G$ and some $T_g G$ so the adjoint transports elements along that unique geodesic?